# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION] running Swiper on Node v16.16.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement Swiper slides in a project, but once I run it on node the terminal throws the following error:

```
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".css" for /Users/gabriel/Documents/Cursos/webdev/personalProjects/cssEfects/slides/swiperSlidesJs/node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.css
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:76:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:118:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:21:20)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:407:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:326:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:66:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:345:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:304:34)
    at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

<index.html>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slides/swiperJsMultiple/styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

<package.json>

```
{
  "name": "swiperjsmultiple",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "swiper": "^10.3.1"
  }
}
```

I did some googling but all I could found were issues related with React/Vue projects. Already checked Swiper Github repo and also couldn't find anything. I'm new to this so I'm not sure if I'm making something wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: it sounds like you need a loader for css files